# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended : When I try to execute INSERT

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have procedure, inside of it, I tried to execute an "insert", but it is sending that error
Can anyone give me a hint to solve this error?
I tried to read the Oracle documentation to figure out where I'm wrong, but so far I have not found anything that can help me.

```
create or replace procedure read_file as  
  begin
     DECLARE 
        V1 VARCHAR2(200); 
        F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
        emptylines number(10):=0;
        read_lines number(10):=0;
        alarm_counter number(10):=0;


     BEGIN 
     --deschidere fisier
        F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ONCIOIU','text.txt','R'); 
     --itinerare fiecare linie din fisierul text   
        Loop
        BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.GET_line(F1,V1); 

    read_lines := read_lines+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(V1);

    -- Determine the number of empty rows
    if V1 is null then
    emptylines :=emptylines+1;
    end if;

    -- Determine the number of alarms
    if emptylines =2 then
    alarm_counter :=alarm_counter+1;
    end if;
    insert into alarms (id)  values(alarm_counter)
    EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found THEN EXIT; END;

        end loop;
         dbms_output.put_line(V1);
         dbms_output.put_line('Numar de linii citite '||read_lines);
         dbms_output.put_line('Numar de randuri goale '||emptylines);
         dbms_output.put_line('Numar de alarme '||alarm_counter);

      -- Close file  
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1); 
     END; 
     end;
     /
```

Comment: remove the `declare`. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm#BABJEGID

Comment: I tried but is not working.

Comment: You are missing the semicolon in your insert statement: `insert into alarms (id)  values(alarm_counter);`

Comment: I  put back "declare" and the missing semicolon and is working. Thanks a lot man !

Comment: Give me an "Answer"  please, to receive points